# is there any function in Python for Aggregating second wise millisecond data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a problem set where the data in a microsecond. I have 4 hours of data as of now. the data set is very huge as it contains microsecond wise data. I want to aggregate each microsecond data into their respective seconds so that it would be helpful for analysis.

**example:**

```
Vibration1   Vibration2  Vibration3  Temperature     Pressure           Time
   816          698          822        1852           710      2019-03-26 09:49:09.013650
   702          690          764        2002           810      2019-03-26 09:49:09.014308
   702          692          768        1888           706      2019-03-26 09:49:09.014680
   696          690          704        2004           810      2019-03-26 09:49:09.015094
   738          696          772        1990           710      2019-03-26 09:49:09.015682
   834          692          704        2066           704      2019-03-26 09:49:09.016153
   798          692          690        1892           722      2019-03-26 09:49:09.016520
   696          722          708        2102           700      2019-03-26 09:49:09.016875
   824          690          700        2058           718      2019-03-26 09:49:09.017213
   692          702          694        2106           704      2019-03-26 09:49:09.017564
```

Like this, I have many rows in the 09th second.
I have a total of 4 hours of data. How should I group by each second with their respective seconds and minutes?

Please help me.

If I am doing `groupby` with seconds its basically grouping all the data with seconds irrespective of its hours, minutes.

I have set the index as DateTime index then I tried with this code. and it returned with some 60 seconds data aggregating irrespective with hours and minutes.

```
df.groupby(df.index.minute).mean()
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for the table and the code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your Time is a `datetime` object:

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
```

Then you need to [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.set_index('Time').resample('1S').mean()
```

With your example data as `df`, the above results in:

```
                 Vibration1  Vibration2  Vibration3  Temperature  Pressure
Time                                                                          
2019-03-26 09:49:09       749.8       696.4       732.6       1996.0     729.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change column 'Time'?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'dates': ['09:49:09.015682', '09:50:09.025682', '09:51:09.055682', '09:49:09.035682', '09:50:09.015682'],
    'values': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in df.index:
    df['dates'][i] = df['dates'][i][:8]

print(df.groupby('dates').mean())
```

Output:

```
          values
dates           
09:49:09     2.5
09:50:09     3.5
09:51:09     3.0
```